# Flex 3 LinkButton: Keep  style unchanged on mouse-hover

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I want a LinkButton's style to stay unchanged when the mouse hovers over it. (But I still want the tooltip to work.) How do I do this?

(The *mouseOver* event seems relevant, and I do a *noop()* on that event, but my goal is to leave the style unchanged rather than do something specific.)

By the way, I am using a non-default style, defining it with CSS in the MXML.

Comment: can you please share the css for the same??

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but you could set the 'overSkin' style to null in your CSS:

```
LinkButton
{
   over-skin:null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An in-line approach:

```
<mx:LinkButton 
    id="mrButton"
    width="80"
    label="Mr. Button"
    skin="{null}"
    toolTip="I am Mr. Button"/>
```